# Why is network-manager adding 10 more seconds to shutdown time?

Tags: network-manager, shutdown

Without network-manager installed, my system shuts down in 2 or 3 seconds.

Why does it take almost 15 seconds (which is a 5-time increase) with network-manager installed and can't this time be shortened?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's bugged & has been for a while now

Main bug with possible self fix
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/869635

Dup bug with alternate self fix
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/903825

This has worked fine here though I'd suggest you read both reports 1st

```
sudo mv /etc/rc6.d/S35networking /etc/rc6.d/S15networking

sudo mv /etc/rc0.d/S35networking /etc/rc0.d/S15networking
```

Or simply wait out a fix if one does show someday. The typical added delay is usually around 500 - 600% of your normal, so here it was 2 sec's to 12 sec's