# Shutdown slow: unknown job s35networking

Tags: networking, 13.04, shutdown, upstart, init.d

Since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.04 LTS, I get this error when I shutdown the pc:

> rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8) utility service S35 Networking stop
>
> initctl: unknown job: s35networking
>
> Since the script yor are attempting to invoke has been convert to an upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop s35networking

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Do you get this error after something like 10 seconds of waiting with the last message being "All processes ended within # seconds"?

Comment: Read this article, believe it can help you :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/102876/why-is-network-manager-adding-10-more-seconds-to-shutdown-time

Comment: There is still the 10-second delay, but the text in question appears much earlier. Since there is no better answer, please add your comment as an answer and I'll award the bounty.

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, this error message does not appear anymore.

Comment: I've traced the delay to `/etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh`:`initctl --quiet emit unmounted-remote-filesystems`. No idea why would initctl stop for ten seconds there.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1230056